# Searching an arrayList for an object and then adding value to that same object more than once

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I just started working with arrayLists - basically what I need to figure out is how to search my arrayList and if that same object is found to add a new total value to it versus just swapping it out.

ie.

```
arrayList = (hats, $45)
```

and I have a new value to add to hats (ie. $10 dollars) - so the ultimate new total for hats = $55

...and if hats are not in the list already to add it.

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: This is unclear.  Are you saying there's an object of your own custom class (call it `Item`) that contains a name ("hats") and a value (45)?  If so, show the declaration of that class.  If you are considering storing the name in the first element of an arraylist and the value in the second element (i.e. `list.add("hats"); list.add(45);`), then you haven't understood array lists yet because that is not going to work.

Comment: Or is it an ArrayList of ints?, and `hats` is an index?

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes I have an entire custom Store class ... so in the main menu when my user inputs an item (which I'm getting from an enum class) ... the store object will get placed into an arrayList (another class) to do all the method checks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filling an ArrayList with String and Integer will not be possible unless you use a nested ArraysList or Map.
But you can create a simple class for your ProductName and the Price and create An ArraysList which contains  for the Name and price.

```
public class Products {

private String product;
private int price;

public Products(String product, int price){
    this.product = product;
    this.price = price;
}
public String getProduct(){
    return this.product;
}
public int getPrice(){
    return this.price;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return this.product +" "+ this.price;
}



public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    ArrayList<Products> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Products("Hat",45));
    list.add(new Products("Socks",10));

    for (Products gd: list){
        if (gd.getProduct().equals("Hat")){
            int index = list.indexOf(gd);
            list.set(index,new Products(gd.getProduct(),gd.getPrice+10));
        }else {
            // if productName not found
            System.out.println("sorry products not available");
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(list);

}
```

}

output:

> [Hat 55, Socks 10]

But if you don't want all this class and want to still use the ArrayList for the job then you can do this with ArrayList containing both name and price

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("Hat,45");
    list.add("Socks,15");

    for (String ss:list){
        String[] spl = ss.split(",");
        if (spl[0].equals("Hat")){
            int index = list.indexOf(ss);
            int value = Integer.parseInt(spl[1])  +10;
            list.set(index,(spl[0]+","+value));
        }
    }


    System.out.println(list);
```

output:

> [Hat,55, Socks,15]

Comment: `gd.product.equals("Hat")` works only because `main` is inside the `Products` class. In the general case you need an accessor such as `getProduct()`.

Comment: @JimGarrison yes, that is why i created the getter. Is that why the down-vote?